# Buisness Models and View Models with multiple languages in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel

I have a .Net web application in VS MVC 4. The solution has 4 projects: Entity_Layer (plain classes), Data_Layer, Business_Layer and MyPj (Main project)

In the **Entities project** I have my entities. Example:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

> In the **main project, in the Models folder** I have my models (or
>   ViewModels). Example:

```
public class ClientModel
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ClientName", ResourceType = typeof(Resource.ResGral))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CientModel(Client C) 
    // When I  get data from Entity layer (through Business Layer)
    {
        Id = C.Id;
        Name = C.Name;
    }

    public Client CientModel_To_Client(ClientModel CM) 
    {
        Client C = new Client();
        C.Id = CM.Id;
        C.Name = CM.Name;
        return C;
    }
}
```

I use those annotations in properties of ClientModel because it's a multi language application. I know these annotations should be only in model of main project (ClientModel) and they should Not be in Entities model (Client) because it's a domain model and has nothing to be with presentation.
That's why I use that constructor and that method to pass from/to Client - ClientModel. 
But I think I am doing double effort. Is this a good idea? If I use inheritance  (ClientModel inheriting from Client) it would useless beacuse I have to write the annotations the same in the ClientModel. Or Maybe I should use hidding properties? 
Please tell me if my current design is a good idea or not.

Comment: check out [Automapper](http://automapper.org/).  You could also project into your view model directly with a linq statement assuming your method is returning a list.  something like  BusinessLayer.GetClients().Select(c => new ClientModel { ... });

Comment: Not its not. Your view models and data models should not be tied together and have dependencies on each other. Use a separate service or [automapper](http://automapper.org/) or just project one into the other  in your controller method (and as a side note, you would not be able to use you view model in a POST method since it does not have a parameterless constuctor)